# How to implement ajaxcontroltoolkit-animation using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I like to implement [this](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/Animation/Animation.aspx) idea in JQuery. I dont want to insert ajaxcontroltoolkit just for that.. I guess the main idea is to use .animate on a div but I dont completely figured out that, javascript isnt exactly my specialty. Can you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See jQuery UI dialog: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ or implement your own via the documentation:

http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Comment: Model form was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!